# eventFilter в QLineEdit

Tags: python, ооп, qlineedit, pyside6, eventfilter

В программе присутствует визуальный баг, если в поле "Возраст" ввести число меньше 18 и больше 80, и нажать на `QPushButton` (кнопка останется серой) или на `QRadioButton` (кружочек окрасится в голубой цвет).

Можно ли как-то это убрать? При нажатие на другое поле `LineEdit`, ничего такого нет.

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class QTApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QTApp, self).__init__()

        self.LE_sample_input_01 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.LE_sample_input_02 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.LE_sample_input_01.setPlaceholderText('Возраст')
        self.RadioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('Что-то')
        self.Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Тык')
        self.Button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:pressed {background-color: #b3b3ba;}")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.LE_sample_input_01)
        layout.addWidget(self.LE_sample_input_02)
        layout.addWidget(self.RadioButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.Button)

        self.LE_sample_input_01.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut and QtGui.QFocusEvent.reason(event) == QtCore.Qt.MouseFocusReason:
            if obj is self.LE_sample_input_01:
                try:
                    age = int(self.LE_sample_input_01.text())
                    if age < 18 or age > 80:
                        error = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
                        error.setWindowTitle('Ошибка возраста')
                        error.setText('Возраст введён неверно (от 18 до 80 лет)')
                        error.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
                        error.addButton('Ок',QtWidgets.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
                        error.exec()
                        obj.setFocus()
                        obj.selectAll()
                        return True
                except: pass
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    qt_app = QTApp()
    qt_app.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
'''
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
'''
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class QTApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QTApp, self).__init__()

        self.le_sample_input_01 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le_sample_input_01.setPlaceholderText('Возраст')
        
        self.le_sample_input_02 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('Что-то')
        
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Тык')
        self.button.setObjectName("button") 
        self.button.setStyleSheet("""
            #button:pressed {
                background-color: #b3b3ba;
            }
        """)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_sample_input_01)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_sample_input_02)
        layout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
        self.le_sample_input_01.installEventFilter(self)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.indicator = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.indicator.hide()
        self.indicator.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('SP_MessageBoxCritical.png'))
        
        self.status_bar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()
        self.status_bar.addPermanentWidget(self.indicator)
        self.status_bar.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        layout.addWidget(self.status_bar, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut and \
            QtGui.QFocusEvent.reason(event) == QtCore.Qt.MouseFocusReason:
            if obj is self.le_sample_input_01:
                try:
                    age = int(self.le_sample_input_01.text())
                    if age < 18 or age > 80:
                        '''
                        error = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
                        error.setWindowTitle('Ошибка возраста')
                        error.setText('Возраст введён неверно (от 18 до 80 лет)')
                        error.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
                        error.addButton('Ок',QtWidgets.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
                        error.exec()
                        '''
                        obj.setFocus()
                        obj.selectAll()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                        text = 'Возраст введён неверно (от 18 до 80 лет)'
                        self.status_bar.showMessage(text, msecs=3000)
                        self.indicator.show()
                        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.indicator.hide)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        return True
                except: 
                    pass
        return False
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt_app = QTApp()
    qt_app.resize(300, 200)                                                  # +++ 
    qt_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

**SP_MessageBoxCritical.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]